# How to use the position value published by joint state publisher in another node?

Tags: ros, ros2, joint-state-publisher, gazebo-plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I am using a gazebo plugin found at /opt/ros/foxy/share/gazebo_plugins/worlds/gazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher. By echo the topic which is /demo/join_states_demo, I can see the position value of my joints. I would like to use those values in another node as an input. May i know how can i do that? Where should I find the source code of plugin?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392550/how-to-use-the-position-value-published-by-joint-state-publisher-in-another-node?/) by [aash](https://answers.ros.org/users/91057/aash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-12-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aash](https://answers.ros.org/users/91057/aash/) on 2021-12-10**:
edit: what is with me is only the .so file which is not readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @aash,

> By echo the topic which is /demo/join_states_demo, I can see the position value of my joints. I would like to use those values in another node as an input.

If you can view **/demo/join_states_demo** by ros2 echo, you just need to write a new subscribe node, and in that, you need to listen to the following topic. You can have a look at this link for [Python code](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html) or [CPP code](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html) for writing a subscriber node.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aash](https://answers.ros.org/users/91057/aash/) on 2021-12-10**:
Hi, thank you for your information.
I have created a subscriber. However, what I have for this plugin is only a .so file which I cannot read what is the code inside. If I am not mistaken, I will need to know the variable name declared in the code that represent the data of the 'position' to subscribe right? for example: position = msg.data.
But the problem right now is the .so file is not readable. Is there any method that allow me to just take the data published at the terminal at put in my subscriber node?

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-12-10**:
Hello @aash,

> I will need to know the variable name declared in the code that represent the data of the 'position' to subscribe right?

If you want the parameter name then use can directly get those parameter names via terminal and that parameter name you can use via your subscriber node.

```
rostopic info /demo/join_states_demo
```

You will get details like message type, Publisher - for a current publisher or not, and Subscriber - current subscriber to a specific topic.

Over here `message type` is very important. Now, you just need to view

```
rosmsg show `message_type_name`
```

You will get a full definition of specific messages and that things you can use for subscribing. Just like `msg.data.<message definition perameaters.>`.

**Comment by [aash](https://answers.ros.org/users/91057/aash/) on 2021-12-10**:
Hi, I am currently using ROS2 Foxy and the command rosmsg is not applicable in ROS, do you know what is the alternative command for ROS2?

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-12-10**:
I am so sorry, I have given you the command for Ros1 and you are using ROS2.

```
ros2 topic info /demo/join_states_demo
```

and for checking message the command is:

```
ros2 interface show <message_name>
```

You can have a look at [this tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces.html#confirm-msg-and-srv-creation) for more details.

**Comment by [aash](https://answers.ros.org/users/91057/aash/) on 2021-12-10**:
what i get is

std_msgs/Header header

string[] name

float64[] position

float64[] velocity

float64[] effort.

May i know with only these information without the .py file, which of these info that i can use for subscribing to this topic?

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-12-10**:
It completely depends on you, Just have a look by echoing into the terminal which data you required, and based on that you can just obtain the data from the subscribed topic.

I would suggest you have a look at the following tutorials for an in-depth understanding of ros2 publisher and subscriber and custom message and services. This will help you a lot in ros development.

https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/index.html

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-12-10**:
If you think, This is a solution for your answer, tick this answer, so it can help others.

**Comment by [aash](https://answers.ros.org/users/91057/aash/) on 2021-12-10**:
I am sorry but I still could not get any further progress from here. Based on my previous reply, the information that i get from ros2 interface show  are not sufficient for me to subscribe to the topic (or maybe I still cant see the way). From the publisher/subscriber tutorial: [link text](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html) , we can see that we need to know what is the output from publisher is declared. In this example,  msg.data = 'Hello World: %d' % self.i. Then in subscriber only i can listen to it with self.get_logger().info('I heard: "%s"' % msg.data).
But for my case, i dont know what is the position, velocity and effort are declared in its original source code hence I dont know the way to subscribe to the output publish by the publisher.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-12-10**:\

> I would like to use those values in another node as an input. May i know how can i do that? Where should I find the source code of plugin?

If you want to use only positions then you can directly subscribe to that channel and you can `position = msg.data.position` and you can use that data to your inputs.

Have a look at http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html, the link for depth explanation about the position, velocity, and effort or you can also ref. to #q320412 for more details about velocity and effort.

> But for my case, i dont know what is the position, velocity and effort are declared in its original source code hence I dont know the way to subscribe to the output publish by the publisher.

If your topic is published -> you are checking if you can view it or not by using the echo keyword.

Then you can easily subscribe to the channel which is published by either CPP or python programming language and you can get published data.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-12-10**:
Can you tell me what package are you using, I will try my best to give you publish code for that, but again if you can see that data is published you can directly subscribe to that channels.